# Why can't gameobject in the hierarchy find it without problems?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to find the GameObject that is in the hierarchy correctly in the hierarchy. But this does not happen correctly, so I want 'if' to work when the gameobject I have tagged is active, but 'if' works even though there is no other gameobject tag, which is why this problem is caused.

Note: My level of English is not good, I try to explain the problem to you as much as I can, please tell me if there is anything you do not understand, I will try to explain it in detail as much as I can. Thank you for your understanding.

1. Image tagged gameobject: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kzV8.png)
2. The point where the problem occurred: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqzEJ.png)
3. Gameobject tag name: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8v7d.png)
4. Cubes Gameobject: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpztE.png)

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (cubes.instance.objPool.Count == 1) //It works when the number of gameobject in the list is 1 when I do a random deletion.
        {
            RewardSystem();
        }
    }
 
 
public void RewardSystem()
    {
        GameObject FoundCube = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(cube_Tag_Number);
 
 
        if (FoundCube == null)
        {
            SoundManager.instance.GameOverMenuSound();
            game_Over_Menu.SetActive(true);
 
            next_Level_Menu.SetActive(false);
            confetti.Stop();
            clickButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            missionButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            enabled = false;
        }
        if (FoundCube != null)// problematic if
        {
            if (FoundCube.activeInHierarchy == true) // problematic if
            {
                SoundManager.instance.NextLevelMenuSound();
                next_Level_Menu.SetActive(true);
                confetti.Play();
 
                game_Over_Menu.SetActive(false);
                clickButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                missionButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
 
 
public class cubes : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static cubes instance;
 
    public int randomRangeNumber1, randomRangeNumber2;
 
    public List<GameObject> objPool = new List<GameObject>();
 
    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else if (instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
 
    }
 
    public void ButtonOnDown()
    {
        SoundManager.instance.LuckButtonSound();
 
         for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
         {
            int index = Random.Range(randomRangeNumber1, randomRangeNumber2);
            GameObject.Destroy(objPool[index]);
            objPool.RemoveAt(index);
 
            randomRangeNumber2 = objPool.Count;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is "cube_Tag_Number". where is it defined?

Comment: Defined in GameControllerLevelFifteen.cs Including RewardSystem ()

Comment: please use the correct tags ... [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now ... your code is clearly `c#`

Comment: Thanks for reporting and editing

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you only want to check the cubes for tags? Currently you iterate over the complete scene. So if any other object has the searched tag, it will return the first object with that tag

Comment: Only 1 out of 6 cubes has a tag and I want it to run if the tagged cube is active in the game. It returns 'if' for a cube with no tag. I just want it to return 'if' if the cube with its tag is active in the game.

Comment: i don't really understand what you mean with returning 'if', but if you only want to search the cubes for the tag you should call the FindGameobjectWithTag() from the Parent (Cube) object. Otherwise it will iterate over your whole scene and if any object of the scene has the mentioned tag it will return that object.

Comment: First of all, I apologize for not being able to explain it fully. I want it to return 'if' for the tagged gameobject but it returns 'if' for the game object without a tag. My goal is I just want it to return 'if' for the tagged gameobject.

Comment: How can I find the gameobject tag in the list?

Comment: still unsure what you mean. do you mean that `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(cube_Tag_Number);` returns a gameobject that does not have the tag? Have you debugged what gameobject it returns with `FoundCube.name` and if `cubes` actually contains all the items you want to check you could just iterate over them and see if they have the tag cubes[x].tag == "[tag]"

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work, I still got the same result.
I will try to explain it in detail as much as I can, I hope I will be successful. The 6 cubes randomly destroy when the button is clicked, and when the cube number is equal to 1, RewardSystem () works, but if the cube I tag is active in the game , I want this command line to work ' if (FoundCube != null) '', but the cube I tag is not active in the game. '' if (FoundCube != null) '' works this line of code I don't want such a thing, how can I fix it?

Comment: then why dont you pass the cube that is left to the RewardSystem `RewardSystem(Gameobject lastCube)` and check `if(lastCube.name =="[TAGINEED]")` instead of the `FoundCube` ifs. Using Find on your hierarchy is not necessary either way if you already know the element that you want to look at. If that is not working that would mean your Tags are setup wrong or the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you very much, I finally got the result I wanted and thank you for your time.